# navigate to row page and highlight the row

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using this jQuery plugin : [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) which manages tables and paging for those tables.

I'm trying to navigate to the page where my `row` is (find the row by Id)
I've found a plugin named fnDisplayRow but I really don't know how to use it.. 
here's what i've wrote so far ( this allows me to highlight a row when i click on it )

what i would like to do now is when i click on `<a href=#rowId> Id </a>`
I would like to change the color of the row and if it's not in the first page then navigate to its page..

```
$("#myTable").on('click','tr', function(){
    var id = otable.row( this ).id();
    $( this ).css('background-color','#ffff99');
    console.log(id);
});
```

Comment: Can you maybe make a jsfiddle? (or your favorite...) I don't understand how someone could click on a row if it's not currently displayed?

Comment: It's working for you?? https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/26/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> page.JumpToData()
>   Jump to a page by searching for data from a column

```js
jQuery.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'page.jumpToData()', function ( data, column ) {
    var pos = this.column(column, {order:'current'}).data().indexOf( data );

    if ( pos >= 0 ) {
        var page = Math.floor( pos / this.page.info().length );
        this.page( page ).draw( false );
    }

    return this;
} );
```

And use it as follows:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
  table.page.jumpToData( "John Doe", 0 );
```

Reference : [page.JumpToData()](https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/api/page.jumpToData())

Comment: Can you tell me how to install it without using the CDN please ? I don't know how to add plugins to Datatables.

Comment: Actually if you see the file it has the same code as the one embedded here. So just use it directly. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to check this for row selection [LINK](https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html)

And this for `row().scrollTo()` [LINK](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row%28%29.scrollTo%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

Ohh, this was a fun one!

Here's my attempt using the suggestion from @Bettimms:

```
$(function() {
  var example01 = $("#example01").DataTable({
    columns: [{
      "visible": false
    }, {
      "render": function(d, m, r) {
        return $("<a></a>", {
          "class": "internal-link",
          "text": d,
          "href": r[0]
        }).prop("outerHTML")
      }
    }, {
      "render": function(d) {
        return (d.length > 25) ? d.substring(0, 25) + "..." : d;
      }
    }]
  });
  var example02 = $("#example02").DataTable({
    columns: [{
        "visible": false
      },
      null
    ]
  });
  $("#example01").on("click", ".internal-link", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr("href");
    example02.page.jumpToData(id, 0);
    example02.rows().iterator("row", function(context, index) {
      var data = this.row(index).data()
      if (data[0] === id) {
        $(this.row(index).node()).addClass("info");
      } else {
        $(this.row(index).node()).removeClass("info");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

With a working JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/1mw7ymh4/). I need to look at `scrollTo()` next as that seems fun too.